# Hidden header takes up white space when exported to pdf in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report where I have a header with Print on first page unchecked.  The header has a rectangle and an image in the background. The Report Previews fine, but when I try to export it to PDF, the first page doesnot have the header but has a white space taken up by the hidden header. Is there a way I can get rid of the white space from PDF. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the report property "ConsumeContainerWhitespace" set to TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an easy answer but have you tried to either set the header size to 0 in Header Properties?

2 - Make sure all items in the header are hidden as well,

3 - Check the report properties to see if the Margin size is affecting this

Let me know if this helps